# Understanding the combination of ufw --force enable

Tags: debian, arguments, ufw

I rent a remote machine with Debian/Ubuntu and desire to filter all ports I don't use through `iptables` via `ufw`.

The only ports I allow (both with TCP and UPD) are `22`,`25`,`80`,`443`.

If I understand `man ufw` correctly `ufw` usually uses for interactive-usage and if we want to use it non-interactively we must "force" such usage. Hence:

1. In Bash script, the syntax `ufw --force` enables it for non interactive usage.
2. By adding `enable` right afterwards (as to get `ufw --force enable`) we both reset the firewall **and also** make `ufw` to recursively being booted after the OS boots.

Is that correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. Have a look at the man page of ufw using `man ufw`. Under REMOTE MANAGEMENT they say:

> When  running  ufw  enable  or starting ufw via its initscript, ufw
>   will flush its chains.
>   This is required so ufw can  maintain  a  consistent  state,  but  it  may  drop  existing
>   connections  (eg  ssh).  ufw  does  support  adding rules before enabling the firewall, so
>   administrators can do:
>
> ufw allow proto tcp from any to any port 22
>
> before running 'ufw enable'. The rules will still be flushed, but the  ssh  port  will  be
>   open  after  enabling  the  firewall. Please note that once ufw is 'enabled', ufw will not
>   flush the chains when adding or removing rules (but will when modifying a rule or changing
>   the  default policy). By default, ufw will prompt when enabling the firewall while running
>   under ssh. This can be disabled by using 'ufw --force enable'.